# ASP.Net Core set Content-Type and Location headers for JSON content

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I have an API resource where you can create a new resource. That looks like so:-

```
    [HttpPost("/content")]
    public JsonResult PostContent([FromBody] ContentCreate content)
    {
        JsonResult result;
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var newContent = _contentService.Create(content);
            result = Json(newContent);
            result.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
            result.ContentType = ContentTypes.VENDOR_MIME_TYPE;
        }
        else {
            var error = new ClientError(ModelState){
                Code = ErrorCodes.INVALID_CONTENT,
                Description = "Content is invalid"
            };
            result = Json(error);
            result.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            result.ContentType = ContentTypes.VENDOR_MIME_TYPE_ERROR;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This works fine as it satisfies my requirements to return a `201` status, and have a vendor specific MIME type for the `Content-Type` header. However, I want to return a `Location` header pointing at the location of the newly created resource. I am not clear on how to add the Location header to the response. I have read about `CreatedResult` which looks almost the perfect fit. However, I see no way to set the `Content-Type` when I use that.

So my question is how do I return JSON, with a `201` status code, with a `Location` header and a custom `Content-Type`?

Answer (score 3):

You could set the header manually. Either directly in the controller or in a custom IActionResult class.

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers["Location"] = "...";
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to address the context directly, as this makes it hard to test.

Comment: Then create your own custom action result. Could be a good idea anyway since it could clear up the controller a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own implementation of an outputformatter, since you want to return Json, and not binary data, you can derive from `TextOutputFormatter` (using the 
namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters`).

In the constructor of that class you can set the content type you want to return:
`SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(ContentTypes.VENDOR_MIME_TYPE));`

The `WriteResponseBodyAsync` accepts a context parameter, you can use this parameter to access the `HttpContext` so you can set the Location header to the response, and also set the HttpStatusCode Created (201).

Finally, register the formatter in the `ConfigureServices` method, in the startup class, by adding it to the MVC Options:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{   
    options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new MyOutputFormatter());
});
```

If you need to go further from here, the Microsoft docs are really good on this subject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters

Comment: This guided me into the right direction. What I could add to this answer is that you can inherit from `JsonOutputFormatter` and just call the `base.WriteResponseBodyAsync` implementation if you like. Another thing I'm not sure is required is to override `CanWriteType` to set it up to accept your specific class instances - the link at the bottom describes how.